# Increment array till a variable's value using ruby array splat

Tags: ruby

I am using the ruby array splat like this:

```
array = *1,2,3 
Output = [1, 2, 3] 
count = 10 #Initializing count
```

**Question:** I want the array to be continued till the `count = 10` when I try this it doesn't work `array = *1,..,count`

**Expected Output:** [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Is there any possible way to succeed with this way of approach.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are `2` and `3` doing?

Comment: Question Edited, I was just showing what I tried first. Basically I was expecting the output to be till count = 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do it this way:

```
array = [*1..count]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
count = 10
*(1..count) # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`Kernel#Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array):

```
Array(1..count)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: I Like `Kernel#Hash` and `Kernel#Array`. so *+1*.

Answer (score 1):

`(1..count)`.to_a, or just `(1..count)` if you need Enumerable object but not explicitly Array.

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 10
count.times.map(&:next)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```